# jQuery UI - Dialog passing custom effect options to the dialog for show and hide

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, dialog

The Dialog widget in jQuery UI has a hide and show options that you can pass the name of effect you want it to run on show and hide events. 
some of the events have extra options like { direction: down } for drop or slide effects but I can not find a way to pass these options to the Dialog widget.

do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no support for sending arguments to uiDialog.hide() or uiDialog.show() other than the name of the effect. However, there is a [patch](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/2358) you can apply. I think this problem will be corrected in 1.8.